# Miracast in Windows Server 2012 R2 (Devices in Charms side bar missing)

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2

I have, so far been able to add my TV to my devices list in Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter edition, However unlike in Windows 8/8.1 I am not able to Project my display content to the TV as I dont see that option in my windows charm side bar.

How can i get my miracast working with my TV ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out Win + P does the job.